# Solutions of $(2x-1)^x\equiv1\mod\ p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Has the equation  $(2x-1)^x\equiv 1\mod{p}$, for $p=1+6qx$, where  $p$, $q$ 
are primes, $x$ is an odd integer
and $x<p$ any solutions except $x=1$?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it appears there are many other solutions.

My Mathematica code:

```
mylist = {{"p", "q", "x"}};
Do[
 Do[p = 1 + 6*Prime[n]*x; 
    If[PrimeQ[p] && PowerMod[2 x - 1, x, p] == 1, 
      AppendTo[mylist, {p, Prime[n], x}]],
   {x, 3, Prime[n], 2}],
{n, 1, 1000}];
TableForm[mylist]
```

It quickly produces the output:

```
p           q       x
5227        67      13
33703       137     41
38923       499     13
82723       811     17
7070611     1117    1055
11005867    2273    807
21914947    3449    1059
29977891    4481    1115
81236131    4759    2845
8616691     5039    285
155351023   5167    5011
138648319   5519    4187
90431851    5531    2725
```

Thus, for example, with $x=13$ and the prime $q=67$, we get the prime
$$p=5227=1+(6\cdot 67\cdot 13)$$
and we can check that
$$(2x-1)^x=25^{13}\equiv 1\bmod 5227$$

With $x=1055$ and the prime $q=1117$, we get the prime
$$p=7070611=1+(6\cdot 1117\cdot 1055)$$
and we can check that
$$(2x-1)^x=2109^{1055}\equiv 1\bmod 7070611$$

Comment: So is trial and error the only way to find a solution?I noticed $x$ comes up as a prime in your results.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any real theory here. Interpreting a number simultaneously as a number mod $p$ and as an exponent is a pretty unnatural thing to do; I doubt there's much we can say about it.

Comment: I've added an example where $x$ is not prime.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explained how this came up for you, what you were expecting, etc.?